# How do I populate a column based off two other columns upon insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just created my own PostgreSQL database.

I have a Person table with a first_name, last_name, and full_name column (also a person_id auto incrementing primary key)

If I insert as such:

```
INSERT INTO Person
(first_name, last_name)
VALUES('Michael', 'Jordan');
```

What's the best approach to automatically populate full_name column as first_name + last_name ('Michael Jordan')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html):

```
alter table person
    add full_name varchar(255) generated always as (concat(firstname, ' ', lastname));
```

Comment: So this would work if I INSERT as well as UPDATE either of the columns?

Comment: @ShadyBears . . . Yes.  This generates `full_name` when you *query* the table, so the value is always accurate.

Comment: I think it would be better to do that concatenation wherever you use it, in the end it would cost less (in terms of hardware/processing) than having duplicated values in your table.